# PyQt5 setPlaybackRate

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudioDecoder

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(246, 134)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
        self.start_mp3(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        
    def start_mp3(self,MainWindow):
        self.output_devices_qt = QtMultimedia.QAudioDeviceInfo.availableDevices(QtMultimedia.QAudio.AudioOutput)
        file_path = r"C:\Users\Χρήστος\Desktop\Papinhio player\project\disket box\mp3 files\ΑΓΙΑ ΚΥΡΙΑΚΗ.mp3"
        self.decode_test_sound(file_path,MainWindow)

    def decode_test_sound(self,file_path,MainWindow):
        self.desiredFormat = QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat()
        self.desiredFormat.setCodec("audio/pcm")
        self.desiredFormat.setSampleRate(44100)
        self.desiredFormat.setChannelCount(1)
        self.desiredFormat.setSampleSize(16)
        self.desiredFormat.setByteOrder(QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat.LittleEndian)
        self.desiredFormat.setSampleType(QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat.SignedInt)
        
        self.m_buffer = QByteArray()
        self.m_buffer_copy = QByteArray()
        
        self.decoder = QAudioDecoder()
        self.decoder.bufferReady.connect(lambda:self.readBuffer(MainWindow))
        self.decoder.setAudioFormat(self.desiredFormat)
        self.decoder.setSourceFilename(file_path)   
        self.decoder.start()
        
        self.play_status = 0
        
    def readBuffer(self,MainWindow):
        buffer = self.decoder.read()
        count = buffer.byteCount()
        if(count>0):
            buffer_data = buffer.constData().asstring(count)
            self.m_buffer.append(buffer_data)
            if(self.play_status!=1):
                self.start_player(MainWindow)
                self.play_status = 1
        else:
            return 1
            
    def timeToSize_1(self):
        return ((self.desiredFormat.channelCount() * (self.desiredFormat.sampleSize() / 8) * self.desiredFormat.sampleRate()) * self.m_time_to_buffer / 1000)
    
    def timeToSize_2(self):

        return ((self.desiredFormat.channelCount() * (self.desiredFormat.sampleSize() / 8) * self.desiredFormat.sampleRate()) * self.MAX_BUFFERED_TIME / 1000)
    
            
    def preplay(self,MainWindow):
        if(self.play_status!=0):
            if(self.m_play_called==False):
                self.m_play_called = True
                self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(MainWindow)
                self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
                self.timer.singleShot(0,lambda:self.sound_mp3(MainWindow))
            
    def sound_mp3(self,MainWindow):
        if(self.play_status!=0):
            self.m_play_called = False
            if self.m_buffer.isEmpty():
                self.stop_player(MainWindow)
                self.m_buffer_requested = True
                return
            elif self.m_buffer.size() < self.m_size_to_buffer:
                if self.m_buffer_requested:
                    return
            else:
                self.m_buffer_requested = False
                
            readlen = int(self.m_audio_output.periodSize())
            chunks = int(self.m_audio_output.bytesFree() / readlen)
            
            
            while (chunks>0):
                samples = self.m_buffer.mid(0, readlen)
                len = samples.size()
                self.m_buffer.remove(0, len)
                if (len>0):
                    if(self.m_audio_output.state()!=2):
                        self.m_output_device.write(samples)
                    else:
                        return 1

                if (len != readlen):
                    break

                chunks = chunks - 1
    
    def start_player(self,MainWindow):
        self.m_play_called = False
        self.m_buffer_requested = True
        self.m_time_to_buffer = 50
        self.MAX_BUFFERED_TIME = 100
        
        if (self.desiredFormat.sampleRate() >= 44100):
            self.internal_buffer_size = (1024 * 10) * self.desiredFormat.channelCount()
        elif (self.desiredFormat.sampleRate() >= 24000):
            self.internal_buffer_size = (1024 * 6) * self.desiredFormat.channelCount()
        else:
            self.internal_buffer_size = (1024 * 4) * self.desiredFormat.channelCount()
            
        #self.m_audio_output = QtMultimedia.QAudioOutput(self.output_devices_qt[self.output_device_index], self.desiredFormat)
        self.m_audio_output = QtMultimedia.QAudioOutput(self.output_devices_qt[0], self.desiredFormat)
        self.m_audio_output.setBufferSize(self.internal_buffer_size)
        
        self.m_size_to_buffer = int(self.timeToSize_1())
        
        self.m_max_size_to_buffer = self.m_size_to_buffer + int(self.timeToSize_2())
        
        self.m_output_device = self.m_audio_output.start()
        
        self.timer_play = QtCore.QTimer(MainWindow)
        self.timer_play.setTimerType(QtCore.Qt.PreciseTimer)
        self.timer_play.timeout.connect(lambda:self.preplay(MainWindow))
        self.timer_play.start(10)
        
    def stop_player(self,MainWindow):
        self.play_status = 0
        self.m_audio_output.stop()
        self.timer_play.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.addLibraryPath(r"C:/Users/Χρήστος/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/pyqt5_tools/Qt/plugins")
    app.addLibraryPath(r"C:/Users/Χρήστος/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins")   
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The above code works well.
**To run the code you must change 3 lines: 24,143 and 144.**
I want:

1. Set playbackrate i search something simillar to `QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer().setPlaybackRate(QReal)`
2. notify i function for change a QSlider (timer)

How can i do 1 and 2?

I am trying to play mp3 files in an output device of my choice.
Then i want to be able to manage sound volume, sound speed and sound position (real time).
Finally, i want to mix some mp3 QByteArray for radio streaming

I think the above aproach is right because i want to mix some mp3 files for a radio streaming.

Comment: Sorry, but after reading your post, I haven't quite gotten what the question was.

Comment: @ewong i just ask how can i do those? (I mean 1 and 2)

Comment: 1. Don't ask two question in one (while they might seem correlated to you, they are not) 2. The playback rate of QMediaPlayer is managed by the internal media player backend, but in your case you're playing *raw audio*; the only way to achieve what you want is to decode the audio and do value interleaving of samples (which is what the backend does when changing the playback rate). This means that you have to *decode* the audio from the source bytes, process it, and then re-encode it again in order to feed the audio output properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, your example is too complex (and, if I may, the whole structure is overly confusing: for instance, continuously calling functions with `ui, MainWindow` arguments is completely unncesessary and makes your code even harder to read than it already is; just make them instance attributes and use those attributes from each method) so I cannot give you an answer as it would take *a lot* of time. I suggest you to look for resources in raw audio decoding using NumPy, and start from that.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the reply. I just updated the code.
I think it's a bit easier to read.

Comment: @ChrisP Sorry, but the situation is not really improved. To be honest, you actually made it worse, as you're clearly modifying a file generated by pyuic (or trying to mimic it), which is something that should **never** be done for lots of reasons (including, as already reported, unnecessary references, issues in modifying the ui, but also great confusion about the object structure). I strongly suggest you to avoid this approach at all costs, and follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead.